# ncurses blit / buffer

Tags: c, ncurses, blit

I am looking for a way to create a "buffer" which I can directly copy, or blit, onto a `WINDOW*` using ncurses. I know there are subwindows, but since the only way to move/ resize them is to create a whole new subwindow, they are not a great fit. I'm looking for something like Microsoft's [WriteConsoleOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput).

Would be nice if I could also copy regions, in a reverse-blit fashion (take rect of `stdscr` and store a copy in a buffer)

Answer (score 0):

windows can in fact be moved or resized without re-creating them:

> [mvwin](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-mvwin)
>
> Calling mvwin moves the window so that the upper left-hand corner is at
>   position  (x,  y).   If  the  move would cause the window to be off the
>   is allowed, but should be avoided.
>
> [wresize](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/wresize.3x.html)
>
> This is an extension to the curses library.  It reallocates storage for
>          an ncurses window to adjust its dimensions to the specified values.  If
>          either  dimension  is larger than the current values, the window's data
>          is filled with blanks that have the current  background  rendition  (as
>          set by wbkgdset) merged into them.
>
> This extension of ncurses was introduced in mid-1995.  It  was  adopted
>          in NetBSD curses (2001) and PDCurses (2003).

Regarding the *question*, updates to a window are based on lines (see [`waddchnstr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addchstr.3x.html) for instance).

Comment: I believe I am looking for a combination of the `newpad` function and the `copywin` function, after some additional research.